# Pre-select multiple items in listbox based on database values

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have a list box that, upon loading the page, I would like to have selected the choices/options that are in the database. It's been a while since I've done anything with list boxes, so I'm a bit confused on how to fix the code for my GetClassification function that is meant to do exactly this. At the moment, it only selects one value in the listbox regardless of the vendor id is associated with more than one.

This is the code for the GetClassification function:

```
protected void GetClassification(int VendorId)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AbleCommerce"].ToString()))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT uidClassification FROM Baird_Vendors_Extension WHERE uidVendor = @VendorId", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorId", VendorId));
        cn.Open();
        using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                vendorType.SelectedValue =reader["uidClassification"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need `@ClassId` since you didn't declare this parameter in your `SqlCommand`.

Comment: ASP.NET is what I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop all items and set the `Selected`-property accordingly:

```
List<string> uidClassificationList = new List<string>();
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int column = reader.GetOrdinal("uidClassification");
        uidClassificationList.Add(reader.GetInt32( column ).ToString());
    }
}
foreach(ListItem item in vendorType.Items)
    item.Selected = uidClassificationList.Contains(item.Value);
```

Apart from that you should be careful with the `SqlParameter` constructor that takes two parameters if the second is an `int` like here:

```
md.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorId", VendorId));
```

The `VendorId` will be casted to `SqlDbType` and a [different overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8f14f0z(v=vs.110).aspx) is used. Instead you should specify the `Value` explicitly:

```
md.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = VendorId });
```

**Edit**: this is also documented in the [remarks-section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Use caution when you use this overload of the `SqlParameter` constructor
>   to specify `integer` parameter values. Because this overload takes a
>   value of type `Object`, you must convert the integral value to an Object
>   type when the value is zero, as the following C# example demonstrates.

```
Parameter = new SqlParameter("@pname", (object)0);
```

> If you do not
>   perform this conversion, the compiler assumes that you are trying to
>   call the SqlParameter (string, SqlDbType) constructor overload.

So this would work also:

```
md.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@VendorId", (object) VendorId));
```

Comment: The only problem with the above is that, for the line inside the while loop, I see this error: The best overload match for System.Data.IDataRecord.GetString(int) has some invalid arguments...

Comment: @gallifrey1212: then it's actually an `int`. I prefer the `Get...` methods since they fail fast if i mistakenly use the wrong datatype and because i don't get implicit conversion(like from `DateTime` including localization issues). Note that i've added my answer.

Comment: Ok, I applied the changes and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the ListBox's SelectionMode property is given as Multiple which will enable the multiple selection.

e.g

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"></asp:ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for how to just select multiple values from the Items(Collection).
You need your SelectionMode to be MultiSimple and then do like this for example

```
listBoxName.SetSelected(0, true);
listBoxName.SetSelected(1, true);
```

In this case the 1st and 2nd values will be pre-selected.

If you need a better [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0#System_Windows_Forms_ListBox_SetSelected_System_Int32_System_Boolean_).